# The exported text file using php would not update

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a problem with my php file to export a query result as a txt file.

When the first time I try the code, it went well and the data inside the txt is correct. But when I try to update the database and export it for the 2nd time, the data inside the 2nd won't update and the content still the same with the 1st exported file. I try to change the exported filename into another name but when i try again, the 3rd exported file still the same with the 1st and the 2nd and even the name still the same as before. This is my code:

```
<?php
  include "config/koneksi.php";

  $scq=mysql_query("SELECT a.tanggal, a.no_cust, a.nama_cust, a.no_sc, b.no_p FROM norder AS a, norder AS b WHERE a.no_sc = b.no_p AND a.tanggal = b.tanggal ORDER BY a.no_cust ASC, STR_TO_DATE(a.tanggal, '%d-%m-%Y') ASC");


  while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($scq)) {
    echo
      "^".$result['no_order']."^,^".$result['no_sc']."^,^".$result['tanggal']."^,^".$result['pengiriman']."^,^".$result['no_cust']."^,^".$result['nama_cust']."^,^".$result['no_p']."^,^".$result['material']."^,^".$result['ppn']."^,^".$result['pembayaran']."^,^".$result['login']."^,^".$result['tahunkirim']."^,^".$result['tanggal2']."^,^".$result['pckg']."^,^".$result['kontrak']."^,^".$result['note']."^,^".$result['cur']."^,^".$result['kurs']."^,^".$result['acc']."^,^".$result['tglacc']."^,^".$result['kdsales']."^,^".$result['nasales']."^,^".$result['luar']."^,^".$result['finishing1']."^,^".$result['note2']."^,^".$result['jkontrak']."^,^".$result['jadwal']."^,^".$result['hrgmf']."^,^".$result['disc']."^,^".$result['jasax']."^,^".$result['kursp']."^;\n";
  }

  header("Content-type: text/plain");
  header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename='test.txt'");

?>
```

I'm using "^" as the subtitute for the quotes inside the txt file. This is my 1st time trying exporting file from PHP code so I'm kinda lost with this.

Comment: The `header` statements should come before you output anything.  Not saying this will necessarily fix things but this may be causing problems.

Comment: Sounds like your browser is caching the file. Maybe add a no-cache header or try different browsers to confirm?

Comment: Both worth to try. I will give feedback after i try it. Thank you guys.

Comment: yes the problem is with the caching. Thank you @JamieKitson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PHP scripts often generate dynamic content that must not be cached by the client browser or any proxy caches between the server and the client browser. Many proxies and clients can be forced to disable caching with:

Try with adding the headers before your current header(). Note sure this will help you.

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename='test.txt'");
```

Comment: Yes the problem is with the caching. Really thank you for the answer.